# Use click handler to change color of button when there are multiple buttons using the same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have three buttons using the same click handler. - My desire is to only change the color of one button when clicked.

If another button is clicked I want the previously clicked button to go back to the color 'blue' (original state).

Example code below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        name: 'bob',
        color: 'blue',
    });

    const handleColor = (e) => {
        setState((state) => ({
            ...state,
            color: 'red',
        }));
    };


    return (
        <div>
         <button style={{ backgroundColor: state.color }} onClick={handleColor}>Click Me</button>
         <button style={{ backgroundColor: state.color }} onClick={handleColor}>Click Me 2</button>
         <button style={{ backgroundColor: state.color }} onClick={handleColor}>Click Me 3</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why not create a react component for the custom button so that each button can have its own state, and not rely on the global state of the parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking something like this

```
const lists = [
  { id: 1, title: "Click 1" },
  { id: 2, title: "Click 2" },
  { id: 3, title: "Click 3" }
];
export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "bob",
    color: "blue"
  });

  const handleColor = (row) => {
    setSelected(row.id);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {lists.map((list) => (
        <button
          key={list.id}
          onClick={() => handleColor(list)}
          style={{ backgroundColor: list.id === selected ? "red" : "" }}
        >
          {list.title}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-hawking-59ds2?file=/src/App.js:64-684)

Comment: Hi Vahid, this answer works for my case. - Can you help me understand why you passed (row) as a prop in the handleColor function? How is row able to reference the lists array? - Also, I notice when I change 'title' to 'name' or any other prop the function does not work as expected. - I'll be happy to mark this as the correct answer but just need to understand this.

Comment: Passing `row` to handleColor allows the component to remember which id is active (via `setSelected(row.id)`) so that on the subsequent render it can be compared to each list item's id (`list.id === selected`) to determine whether it should be rendered in red.

Comment: #rayhatfield thanks for the explanation. @Dr. Tenma you can check #ray hatfield  comment. As you asked about title/name, better to handle through id because text can be duplicated not id's.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense and I will mark as correct. If you have a moment please view my sandbox as it mimics my local environment. Really need to know if what I am doing is bad practice (I am passing everything as state to a child component). Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-lake-r7h17?file=/src/Button.js

Comment: @Dr.Tenma code looks good...only remove const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0); because you are already using *selected* in your state.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one button active at a time, keep track of which one is active instead of what color it is.

```
// hypothetical list of buttons. these could be objects with labels, etc.
// but for the purposes of this example they're just empty slots.
const buttons = Array(3);

// the index of the currently active button
const [active, setActive] = useState();

return (
  <div>
    { buttons.map((button, index) => ( // render a button for each item in the array
      <button
        style={active === index ? { backgroundColor: 'red' } : {}}
        onClick={() => setActive(index)}>
          Click Me
      </button>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to maintain separate state for each button.
you can do something like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Parent() {

    const initialButtonState = {
        color1: 'blue',
        color2: 'blue',
        color3: 'blue',
    } 


    const [state, setState] = useState({...initialButtonState , name: 'bob'});

    const handleColor = (colorName) => {
        setState((state) => ({
            ...state,
            ...initialButtonState ,
            [colorName] : 'red'
        }));
    };


    return (
        <div>
         <button style={{ backgroundColor: color1 }} onClick={ () => handleColor("color1))}>Click Me</button>
         <button style={{ backgroundColor: color2 }} onClick={() => handleColor("color2")}>Click Me 2</button>
         <button style={{ backgroundColor: color3 }} onClick={() => handleColor("color3")}>Click Me 3</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```